# neo4j app does not work on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, neo4j

I have an issue in my project

It is based on nodejs , and using neo4j graph db as database

I developed it and uploaded to heroku

It worked well and i add to login function into app

It works well on localhost , so i uploaded to heroku again , but then it does not operate now

I added express-handlebars , express-validator  , connect-flash module

I can not understand why the app does not work on heroku , instead of it works well on my localhost

If you have methods to solve this , then please reply to me

Thank you

Regards

Comment: You should describe your problem clearly, "it does not operate" cannot help much, maybe you can show us some errors on console, some of your code, or a screenshot etc.

Answer (score 0):

One reason could that you have no Neo4j database available.

You should configure the database URL via an environment variable and then get a Neo4j instance via either GrapheneDB or GraphStory as Heroku Add-On.

Both providers should have documentation and code-snippets on how to use their offering.

Both use different environment variable names, so take note.
Then pass that URL to your driver.